# Pinescript - draw a box around candle wicks on different timeframes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, indicator

im trying to create an indicator that shows the 5min Unmitigated Bull and Bear Wicks in a box forward until they are then mitigated entirely by a candle in the future

```
//@version=5
indicator("5minBoxes", overlay=true, max_boxes_count=500, max_lines_count=500)

//Candles
upBar = close >= open
downBar = open >= close
bullWick = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", upBar and high - close)
bearWick = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", downBar and close - low)

// Create variables
var bullBoxTop = bullWick and high
var bullBoxBottom  = bullWick and close
var bearBoxTop = bearWick and open
var bearBoxBottom = bearWick and low
var box bullBox = na
var box bearBox = na

// Other inputs for the boxes' visual appearance
boxBorderSize   = input.int(2, title="Box border size", minval=0)
bullBoxColor      = input.color(color.new(color.green, 85), title="Up box")
bullBorderColor   = input.color(color.green, title="Up border")
bearBoxColor    = input.color(color.new(color.red, 85), title="Down box")
bearBorderColor = input.color(color.red, title="Down border")

//plot the boxes
if bullWick
    bullBox := box.new(left=bar_index, top=na, right=na, bottom=na, border_width=na)

if bearWick
    bearBox := box.new(left=bar_index, top=na, right=na, bottom=na, border_width=na)
```

it no longer errors, but i definately think im missing something in regards to actually drawing the boxes. i also only want boxes drawn for the last 500 candles
then im not sure how to say... if the box has a candle or wick go all the way thru it, remove urself

can anybody help?

Thanks